# I do not see a bounty option option on any questions

Tags: support, bounty

I've only opened one bounty before and it was closed. Now I am trying to open a bounty on several old questions (or at least see if I have the ability to do so), and I do not see that option. I thought the only things which blocked you from opening a bounty were having 3 open counties or trying to open a bounty on a question which is less than 48hrs old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, you can't place bounties on new questions or have more than three open bounties at a time.

However, you also [need 75 reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) before the system will let you place any bounties at all. As I'm writing this, your rep is at 61, so you're still a few upvotes short.

For all the details, see [the network-wide community FAQ page on bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I didn't know my rep was that high previously when I had set one for 50pts. Thank you.